# Why wont this program run, but it will build?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have been trying to run this average calculator program in code blocks, and it builds without error but it can't run for some reason and I have no idea why. 
My code is below

```
#include < iostream >

  using namespace std;

double getAverage(int amount, int numbers[]) {
  // Declare the variables
  int total = 0;
  double avg = 0;
  //Find each number in the array then add it to the total
  for (int i = amount; i > 0; i--) {
    total += numbers[i];

  }
  //Divide the total by the amount to get the average
  avg = total / amount;
  cout << "The Average is: ";
  //Return the average
  return avg;
}

int main() {
  // Declare the variables and arrays
  int varNum = 1;
  int totVar;
  int userNums[totVar];
  //Ask user for how many variables they want then record it
  cout << "How many variables would you like to have? ";
  cin >> totVar;
  //Ask the user for each variable, then record it into the array
  for (int i = totVar; i > 0; i--) {
    cout << "Please input variable " + varNum;
    cin >> userNums[i];
    varNum++;

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initialize `totVar` before you create the array `userNums`.

Comment: It doesn't build for me.

Comment: Declaring userNums as std::vector can solve many issues.

Comment: It builds for me for some reason.

Comment: `int userNums[totVar];` -- This is not legal C++, as arrays cannot be declared using a variable as the number of items.  This code will fail to compile with an ANSI compliant C++ compiler [(example here)](http://rextester.com/SLFM33724), and will fail to compile (you're probably using `g++`) with the following command-line arguments: `-Wall -pedantic`.

Comment: It's easy to write code, that compiles, but fails instantly. If code with bugs, failed to compile, there would be no need for QA..

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @AmanoDude *Why wont this program run, but it will build?* -- If I write a program that is supposed to add two numbers, but instead subtracts two numbers, it will build with no errors.  Does that mean the program works correctly?

Comment: No, it wouldn't, but the problem I was having was that it shut down the program and then closed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **three** issues with this code. **First**, as @stefan said, `totVar` has not been initialized when it's used as the array size. But that doesn't matter because, **second**, `int userNums[totVar];` is not legal C++ (it compiles because of a GCC extension). And **third**, those loops

```
for (int i = totVar; i > 0; i--) {
    cout << "Please input variable " + varNum;
    cin >> userNums[i];
    varNum++;
}
```

and

```
for (int i = amount; i > 0; i--) {
    total += numbers[i];
}
```

pass invalid indices to the array. An array of size N has valid indexes from 0 to N-1. The first pass through that first loop accesses `numbers[totVar]`, which is off the end of the array. The usual way to write a loop like the first one is

```
for (int i = 0; i < totVar; ++i)
    cin >> userNums[i];
```

This accesses the values at `numbers[0]`, `numbers[1]`, ... `numbers[totVar-1]`.

Do the same thing for the second loop.

Comment: Ahmm.. good point about `int userNums[totVar]`, I think I was mixing it with some C#. You deserve the answer-score-bonus here.

Comment: Thank you. This sure helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**see: @Pete Becker for an actual answer**

You need to initialize `totVar` before you create the array `userNums`

As you are using

```
cin >> totVar;
```

Later in your software you might want to give it an upper bound.

```
int userNums[1000];
```

And check `totVar` doesn't exeed 999.

Comment: Thank you, but does the array fill all the excess data in with 0's or something? For example, lets say I put 16 pieces of data in the array, would it fill the excess space in the array with 0's?

Comment: @PeteMcGreete No, it won't. If you want to initialize your array, you may want to write `int userNums[1000] = {};`